# How to concetenate several letters into one unique character string?

Tags: r

I've already checked for many R functions from stringr package but I can't find the right answer. I'm trying to turn a number for instance 2211578 into a character string in which each letter is given by the integer at each place in my global number. For instance, if my number is 2211578 i'll get the character string "bbaaegh". I've already tried this, which gives me the right letters but i can't concatenate them into one single string.

```
x <- 12384579
x.string <- str_c(letters[26 - as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(Reverse_number(x)), "")[[1]])])))
```

where Reverse_number is the following function:

```
Reverse_number <- function(x){ 
n <- trunc(log10(x)) # now many powers of 10 are we dealing with 
x.rem <- x # the remaining numbers to be reversed 
x.out <- 0 # stores the output 
for(i in n:0){
  x.out <- x.out + (x.rem %/% 10^i)*10^(n-i) # multiply and add 
  x.rem <- x.rem - (x.rem %/% 10^i)*10^i # multiply and subtract 
} 
return(x.out) 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
# example number
x = 2211578

# get each character separately
y = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split="")))

# get corresponding letters and combine them
paste0(letters[y], collapse = "")

# [1] "bbaaegh"
```

You can use the above as a function:

```
GetLetterString = function(x) {paste0(letters[as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), split="")))], collapse = "")}

GetLetterString(2233)

# [1] "bbcc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your number to convert

```
x <- 2211578
```

Convert to character vector and split on every character

```
str <- strsplit(as.character(x),"")[[1]]
```

Convert back to integer and select corresponding letters

```
str <- letters[strtoi(str)]
```

Paste to create a single string.

```
str <- paste0(str,collapse = "")
str
# [1] "bbaaegh"
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly!

Comment: I forgot the argument collapse the first time i tried paste0 that's why